# Image Uploading to firebase successfully but not showing in phone

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, picasso

I am trying to build a messenger type app. And for this, I have uploaded an image from my phone to firebase. And the image is successfully stored in firebase storage. And I am trying to show the image on my phone. And I use Picasso to retrieve the image from firebase. But my picture isn't showing. But when I add placeholder I can see the default image that is set by a placeholder. How can I solve this problem? My code is given below:

```
package com.example.whatsapp2;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button UpdateAccountSetting;
    private EditText userName, userStatus;
    private CircleImageView userProfileImage;
    private String currentUserId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference RootRef;
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImagesRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private Toolbar SettingsToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        UserProfileImagesRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

        InitializeFields();

        userName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        UpdateAccountSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UpdateSettings();
            }
        });

        RetrieveUserInfo();

        userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GalleryPick);
            }
        });

    }

    private void RetrieveUserInfo() {
        RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name")) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))){
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                    Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                    //Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).resize(100,100).centerCrop().into(userProfileImage);
                }
                else if((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("name"))){
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                    userName.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    userStatus.setText(retrieveStatus);
                }
                else {
                    userName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please set & update your profile information...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void UpdateSettings() {
        String setUserName = userName.getText().toString();
        String setStatus = userStatus.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setUserName)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your user name first....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(setStatus)) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please write your status....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
            profileMap.put("uid", currentUserId);
            profileMap.put("name", setUserName);
            profileMap.put("status", setStatus);
            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).updateChildren(profileMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Updated Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error : "+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void InitializeFields() {
        UpdateAccountSetting = findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userStatus =findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        userProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        SettingsToolbar = findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(SettingsToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Account Settings");
    }


    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
            //userProfileImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your profile image is updating...");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserId+".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Image uploaded Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image save in Database Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        String message = task.getException().toString();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error:"+message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by simply adding 1 line of code:

```
//in this block 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null ) {

        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

        userProfileImage.setImageURI(ImageUri); //add this line
```